# NSMutableDictionary, Sending void to paramater of type id_Nullable

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults, nsmutabledictionary

I am relatively new to iOS, and facing a problem while saving a dictionary and updating it in NSUserDefaults... This is my implementation .

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"KEY"]) {
        [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"KEY"] setObject:someString forKey:otherKey];
    } else {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[self.dictionary setObject:someString forKey:otherKey] forKey:@"KEY"];
    }
```

I am checking for a "KEY initially in userdefaults and if that key doesn't exist i want to set a dictionary as object for key "KEY" and next time when control come here since the "KEY" would existit will take the dictionary against the "KEY" and set another object in dictionary. someString and otherKey are coming from the calling function.

I am getting "Sending void to paramater of type id_Nullable", i know setObject wants some object and its receiving void here but what to do now. I am lost.

I think i am lacking some basics here, kindly help someone. Thanks!!

Comment: There are indeed some issues with your code, my best tip is to decompose, use intermediary var to understand what is going one. If there are more than 2 square brackets, use another var, another line, you'll see where are your errors then.

Comment: There ought to be a compiler warning.....?

Answer (score 0):

setObject method returns nil, which you are trying to set in [NSUserDefault standardUserDefaults]. Refer below updated code for the solution:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"KEY"]) {
        //'objectForKey' returns nullable id and not NSDictionary, so you can't directly treat as dictionary
        //[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"KEY"] setObject:someString forKey:otherKey];
        //Change it to below code
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"someString" forKey:@"KEY"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dict forKey:@"otherKey"];

    } else {
        //'setObject' method returns nil, which you are trying to set in [NSUserDefault standardUserDefaults]
        //[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[self.dictionary setObject:someString forKey:otherKey] forKey:@"KEY"];
        [self.dictionary setObject:someString forKey:otherKey];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.dictionary forKey:@"KEY"];

    }
```